# What is the effect of viewing pornography on children?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology, sexuality, parenting

It is generally accepted that porn shouldn't be seen by children, and we even sometimes punish parents who fail to stop their children from finding porn.

How much are these laws based in science? Can a simple image cause real injury beyond mere disgust? Have there been any studies that track lives of people who were exposed to porn or other disturbing imagery as children or adolescents?

Note that [I have also posted this question on parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8664/what-harm-is-porn).

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to find enough volunteers for an experiment (though you could find some victims and talk to them)

Comment: @JohnDvorak Victims? I've seen porn when I was a child, and I was not victimized by that.

Comment: Mere viewing isn't going to have an effect. Continued exposure for a considerable term without proper education about sexual health along with dopamine+serotonin releases due to stimulation of genitalia/gratification from viewing acts is what can have an effect on the brain. It is the hormones that effect the brain, naked bodies do nothing. Speaking from personal experience. I've experimented all of it myself on my own mental health. And I'm still fighting my urges everyday to be completely free from it. Also, the health of the mind prior to and during initial exposure has a say.

Answer (score 16):

Pornography laws are a [relic of the Victorian era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography#History), and not based on any science.

Research that can conclusively determine the effect of pornography on children is hard to come by due to the resultant ethical environment.  Most research depends on self-reports: Surveys ask adolescents how much pornography they have been exposed to, and attempt to correlate this with other variables such as personal attitudes about sex.  Such surveys are subject to a variety of memory and other biases affecting accuracy, but more importantly, correlations fail to establish cause and effect - that is, it is equally likely that pornography consumption affects attitudes as it is that pre-existing attitudes affect pornography consumption.

Nonetheless, a [number of reviews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_pornography#School-age_juveniles) of current literature on adolescents conclude that there is an association between consumption of pornography and certain negative attitudes about sex, and promiscuous and/or risky sexual behaviour.  The reviews acknowledge that the data contains much contradictory evidence however, as well as failing to establish cause and effect.

UK Children's Commissioner's report (2013): "[Basically... Porn is everywhere](https://eprints.mdx.ac.uk/id/eprint/10692)"

Owens et al (2012): "[The Impact of Internet Pornography on Adolescents](https://doi.org/10.1080/10720162.2012.660431)"

In contrast, a paper by [Kendall (2006)](http://idei.fr/sites/default/files/medias/doc/conf/sic/papers_2007/kendall.pdf) found a correlation between pornography accessibility and rape for 15-19 year old adolescents - but in the opposite direction, that could be interpreted to mean that access to pornography reduces rape crime in this demographic.  A meta-analysis by [Wright, Tokunaga, & Kraus (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1111/jcom.12201) found no difference between adults and adolescents in association between pornography consumption and sexual aggression.

Research on pre-adolescents is even more scant.  A more conclusive effect is seen between exposure to depictions of violence and negative effects on attitudes and behaviour, though these may be short-lived.  A [landmark study](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobo_doll_experiment) from the 1960's (no longer ethical to replicate) demonstrated that children do role model from violent media.  The reviews listed above extend this finding to attitudes and behaviours of adolescents exposed to pornography depicting violence.  Evidence linking this to criminal offences in adulthood is [still controversial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effects_of_pornography#Sexual_violence) however.

In adults, studies across multiple countries (eg, [Diamond, Jozifkova, & Weiss, 2010](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10508-010-9696-y)) have documented significant declines in physical sex offenses as accessibility of pornography increases, again suggesting the possibility that pornography provides a substitute for sex crimes.

Answer (score -5):

So I cross posted this question to Parenting Stack Exchange, and [here's what I got](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/8664).

In short, people who have viewed porn as adolescents have more sex and greater risk of sexually transmitted disease. And some of the kids who have stumbled upon porn on the Internet became averse to the Internet and some others developed unwanted recurring thoughts about the material they had seen.

Comment: Imagine your child has been abused and murdered. And now you stumble upon a very graphic image documenting the deed on an imageboard like 4chan (where I in fact stumbled upon images of child pornography in the "random" section). How do you think that image would affect you? I'm pretty sure it would shock you to the core and never leave your mind again ever. I don't understand why you focus on pornography as the only harmful kind of image.

Comment: @Ansis, if you read my review of that one study the guy quoted and you paraphrased as "And some of the kids who have stumbled upon porn on the Internet 
became averse to the Internet and some others developed unwanted recurring thoughts about the material they had seen."  You'll see the study has some serious flaws.

Comment: @AnsisMalins Actually, the bulk of my response is that "porn most often depicts intimate relationships in a highly unrealistic fashion, and therefore can be confusing or misleading to children". The *Psychology Today* blog, and the findings from the survey of children exposed to "unwanted" porn, were merely added to provide some additional areas of concern. Taal is right that there are flaws in the study, but its a bit problematic to do proper controlled scientific studies on this without running afould of major ethical concerns.

Comment: @Beofett if they are highly inaccurate and could be argued as extremely, extremely skewed to the point where I can use them to actually cite my own opposing viewpoint - then I believe they should have never been published in the first place, but they certainly shouldn't be cited or repeated by anyone.  There are problems with figuring out the answers to these questions - and I actually pointed out all of those problems so that perhaps some researcher in the future can take note of and account for them. I wish you did not delete my informative post at parenting as it will cause misinformation

Comment: @Taal As I said on parenting, a long, rambling diatribe that in no way addresses the question, and instead is filled with completely random and irrelevant information, should not be posted as an answer. If you think my answer will cause "misinformation", please feel free to post your own answer.  Then you can self-declare "victory" through altered screenshots of video games to your heart's content :)  Just be sure to post an actual answer, and not an off-topic lecture.

Comment: I posted my own answer here, but the questions are different. "a long, rambling diatribe that in no way addresses the question, and instead is filled with completely random and irrelevant information, should not be posted as an answer."  Dude, you just threw labels onto the flaws I pointed out in your study that people are now reading and going by.  In academia people respond to research and clinical studies all the time - that is how one gets closer to the truth.  It would be preferable if you had a response (actually there were holes in my I purposely left open to see if you'd try). @Beofett

Comment: @Beofett ^continuation from above.  To be clear, you and I both know that my information was accurate and correct.  If I feel like it is important to bring what you cited as incorrect, and so much so that I can use it to strengthen my argument, then I would prefer that you form a rebuttal instead of deleting and then posting things like the one above that are completely untrue.  Also, as I said I purposefully left very small holes in my argument hoping someone would at least try to break it down - but no one cares or seems to care...they just delete.

Comment: @Taal A) It is not "my" study.  It is a survey conducted by a research team, the contents of which comprised exactly two sentences of my entire answer. B) Comments are not a place to debate, or form "rebuttals".  Comments are a place to post clarifications or ask for clarifications. What you want is not what the SE platform is for. If you want a "discussion", chat is the only valid place for it (hopefully with the outcome being an improved answer).  I am done responding to you here and on parenting.se. If you want to join a chat, I might consider it, but only if you can discuss it civilly.

Comment: @Beofett You already know all of my opinions assuming you've read them.  I'm not sure why you think my responses are uncivil besides the mortal kombat picture.  I'm not throwing labels onto you, calling you names, or saying things like "long, rambling diatribe that in no way addresses the question, and instead is filled with completely random and irrelevant information."

Comment: @Beofett A) It doesn't matter if it's yours or whoever's study it is, its the fact that it's extremely inaccurate information in the top voted answer's spot.  Don't you feel some responsibility to post a study that is actually valid research, one in which you know people will read? Example: look at the last two sentences of the OPs response here.  They regard your study.  B) I'm aware of the semantics of what comments are "for" - but for me to see something I know people are reading that is so invalid I feel I have a duty to inform them of what the truth is - regardless of the medium or rules.

Comment: @Beofett There is no need to go to chat as I've explained all the flaws in that study 4 times now - it is very bad.  The only thing that would happen in chat is I would try to convince you to remove that part of your post, because you're essentially hurting people with misinformation as well as lowering the sites credibility.  Especially as a moderator in that section, your goal should not be to do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10401/discussion-between-beofett-and-taal)